# Parallel for loop in Java 8 - follow-up

Tags: java, concurrency, iteration, lambda

The previous and initial iteration at [Parallel for loop in Java 8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73930/parallel-for-loop-in-java-8).

Changes are as follows:

1. `ParallelLoopBody` removed; `java.util.Function` used instead.
2. The actual parallel loop synchronizes on a class monitor.
3. `forp` does not ask for the output list in arguments; instead, it creates a new list of output data on each call.

The modified files:

`ParallelFor.java`:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.function.Function;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utilities.checkNotNull;

/**
 * This class implements the parallel for loop. It is assumed that two distinct
 * tasks in the loop are independent, i.e., one task needs no output data from
 * another task.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version I
 */
public class ParallelFor {

    /**
     * The thread pool doing the actual work.
     */
    private static final ForkJoinPool POOL;
    private static final Object PARALLEL_LOCK;

    static {
        POOL = new ForkJoinPool();
        PARALLEL_LOCK = new Object();
    }

    /**
     * Implements the actual parallel for loop.
     * 
     * @param <I>        the type of input data.
     * @param <O>        the type of output data.
     * @param inputList  the list of individual arguments to the routine to 
     *                   parallelize.
     * @param body       the actual function transforming an input datum into a
     *                   output datum. May be specified in the form of a 
     *                   lambda expression.
     * @return the list of output data in the same order as input data.
     */
    public static final <I, O> 
        List<O> forp(final List<I> inputList,
                     final Function<I, O> body) {
        synchronized (PARALLEL_LOCK) {
            // Create the tasks.
            final List<MyTask<I, O>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(inputList.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); ++i) {
                    tasks.add(new MyTask<>(body, inputList.get(i)));
                }

            final List<Future<O>> futures = POOL.invokeAll(tasks);
            final List<O> output = new ArrayList<>(futures.size());

            futures.stream().forEach((future) -> {
                try {
                    final O out = future.get();
                    output.add(out);
                } catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    output.add(null);
                }
            });

            return output;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implements the actual individual task.
     * 
     * @param <I> the type of input data.
     * @param <O> the type of output data.
     */
    private static class MyTask<I, O> implements Callable<O> {

        /**
         * Contains the actual code for transforming input to output.
         */
        private final Function<I, O> body;

        /**
         * The input datum.
         */
        private final I input;

        /**
         * Constructs a new task which requires output.
         * 
         * @param body        the loop body implementation.
         * @param input       the input datum.
         */
        MyTask(final Function<I, O> body, final I input) {
            checkNotNull(body, "The parallel loop body is null.");
            this.body  = body;
            this.input = input;
        }

        /**
         * Runs this task by transforming input using the loop body to output 
         * and stores it in the output list (if needed).
         * 
         * @return <code>null</code> as a dummy return value.
         */
        @Override
        public O call() throws Exception {
            return body.apply(input);
        }
    }
}
```

`Demo.java`:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import static net.coderodde.util.ParallelFor.forp;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utilities.listsEqual;

/**
 * This class contains the entry point to the demo demonstrating the parallel 
 * for loop and provides some demo-related utility methods.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @versio I
 */
public class Demo {

    private static final int INPUT_LENGTH = 50;
    private static final int MIN = 10;
    private static final int MAX = 40;

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Long> output = new ArrayList<>();
        final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Random rnd = new Random(seed);
        final List<Integer> inputList = getRandomInputList(INPUT_LENGTH,
                                                           MIN,
                                                           MAX,
                                                           rnd);

        final List<Long> serialResult = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (final Integer i : inputList) {
            serialResult.add(hardFibonacciWork(i));
        }
        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Serial time: " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //// CHECK THIS OUT: MY FUNKY PARALLEL FOR
        final List<Long> parallelResult =
                forp(inputList, (i) -> hardFibonacciWork(i));
        //////////////////////////////////

        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Parallel time: " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        boolean identical = listsEqual(serialResult, parallelResult);

        System.out.println("Output lists identical: " + identical);

        if (identical) {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.printf("%2d: %-10d %-10d\n", inputList.get(i),
                                                    serialResult.get(i),
                                                    parallelResult.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    private static long hardFibonacciWork(final int i) {
        if (i <= 0) {
            return 0L;
        }

        if (i == 1) {
            return 1L;
        }

        return hardFibonacciWork(i - 1) + hardFibonacciWork(i - 2);
    }

    private static List<Integer> getRandomInputList(final int size,
                                                    final int min,
                                                    final int max,
                                                    final Random rnd) {
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            list.add(rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyTask` seems unneccesary. You can make `tasks` a list of `Callable<O>` and then add tasks with a lambda instead:

```
tasks.add(() -> body.apply(inputList.get(i)));
```

You're using `forEach` on the stream, but the operation you're doing more closely matches `map`. I'd try to use that instead.

The stream api can already do this with `parallelStream` and `map`:

```
public static final <I, O> List<O> forp(final List<I> inputList, final Function<I, O> body) {
    return inputList.parallelStream()
        .map(body)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You're catching exceptions and silently replacing with `null`. If this is what you want, document it in the javadoc.
Alternatively, you could throw an exception from `forp`.

The thread-safety problems are going to come from other threads manipulating `inputList` or side-effects
executed within `body`. The synchronization you have isn't preventing this, but I would say it's the caller's
responsibility to not do anything like that. You could actually just remove the synchronization.